# Generate customized password with seed python

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a password using a seed in Python and I want the ability to customize the length

I found the Faker library which let me generate passwords with seed but I am unable to customize the output, code below

```
from faker import Faker


class Password:

    f0 = Faker()
    Faker.seed(1234)

    print(f0.password())
    print(f0.sentence())
    print(f0.msisdn())

output:
tA1b&i5ck*
Require suddenly me they.
1871918904814
```

I could not find documentation for customizing faker length (I can truncate the output sure, but what if I want longer?) in python so are there arguments im missing ?

Else is there another library that generates customizable strings using seeds?

Comment: Is this for testing purposes or are you actually trying to generate passwords that will be used somewhere?

Comment: I will save the output to json

Comment: For what purpose? The question is: how random does this need to be?

Comment: What is "faker"? A link would be good.

Comment: Please include the link to the documentation of the `password` function that you're using. Can't be the one I found.

Comment: luk2302:not sure how to define randomness. Im farily new haha

kelly: https://pypi.org/project/Faker/

Comment: Link to the `password` function please.

Comment: kelly: I found it on one stack overflow question but I could not find it in the docs

Comment: Strange. For me, it's the first result in the doc's search. And easy to find in the index as well.

Comment: `I will save the output to json` still does not answer the question. It is 2023, do not store passwords in plaintext. I really struggle to come up with a scenario where you would not store hashes even in the early testing. Externally seeded passwords are a legit use case, J_H gives you two main options for your testing needs.

Answer (score -1):

Simply truncate the returned value, as desired.

```
k = 8

print(f0.password()[:k])
```

If you want it longer, it isn't hard to go to the trouble
of consulting the
[documentation](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.misc.html#faker.providers.misc.Provider.password):

> password(length: int = 10, special_chars: ...)
>
> Generate a random password of the specified length.

Use

```
k = 80

print(f0.password(k))
```

———

Also, sha3() hexadecimal hash output makes for terrific passwords.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: what if I want it longer?

Comment: Why do that instead of using the `password` function properly?

Comment: Why not use `secrets.token_urlsafe` or `secrets.token_hex` assuming 3.6+? Edit: you're right, seeding makes sense sometimes. Sorry.